# Ionic 3 I can't call data with SQLite

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using SQLite on the project. I perform events like insert operations in database operations successfully. But I do not know how to reach the data when it brings the data. I am trying to create a list of the following code fragment. I'm waiting for your help.

```js
GRUPLISTESI : any;
  GRUPLAR(){
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM 'GRUPLAR'";
    this.db.executeSql(sql, {}).then((data)=>{
      this.GRUPLISTESI = data["rows"]; //What should I write here?
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the data from your Ionic sqlite database like this:

```
db.executeSql("SELECT * FROM test")
    .then(result => {
        console.log(result.rows.item(0).id);
    });
```

So abstract it would look like so: `result.rows.item([row]).[column_label]`.

For some deeper examples on how to use sqlite for Ionic, you can use this repository: https://github.com/didinj/ionic3-angular4-cordova-sqlite-example

Comment: This solution is not the way

Comment: Did I missunderstand you? This is the way to access the data